# Primeng table very slow with virtual scroll and expanded rows

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable, primeng-table

The table loads super and editing is also slow to start when `rowexpansion` is added for large data 2000 rows by 64 columns and 10000 rows by 5 columns. It looks like lazy load is not implemented on it. I was thinking of just loading expanded rows only when the button is clicked. I tried to bind with `*ngIf` and the expand button click but it didn't expand. Even conditionally disabling using *ngIf for tables with no related record didn't work. Is there any way of making it lazy load?

I have live example in [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablevirtualscroll-demo-s5ee62?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is a bug on primeng but I found a good workaround. Mainly, the solution involves removal of rowexpansion completely and replacing it by `<tr>` that will contain a div or another component that appears conditionally when the Expand button is clicked.

See the updated [**stackbitiz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablevirtualscroll-demo-v5acg2?file=src/app/app.component.html) with no lag.

Comment: Hi, I got similar issue, thanks for the demo, but the row does not seem to be expandable, can you double check it?

Comment: Sorry, let me re-check it

Comment: @HoàngNguyễn I made few update. The updated one has an empty `<tr>` on line 41. In the `<tr>` you need to show it conditionally on click on the expansion button that contains a related table. The difference between the two demos is, the first one has rowexpansion and the second one has just `<tr>`.